# Iwama ryu bokutō

Tags: aikido, weapons

[Iwama ryu](http://takemusu-iwama-aikido.org/) uses a differently shaped (from the classical shape) bokutō to practice. Why does it have the shape it has and why is it the preferred shape for [Iwama ryu](http://takemusu-iwama-aikido.org/)?

Here are some images:

[image: bokutō] [image: bokutō]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in iwama ryu we have lot of contacts with stabbing (tsuki) so it would be less dangerous to stab with blunt kisaki.

Second, there are go no awase and shichi no awase which are parrying techniques, practitioner should parring in proper way, if he parry wrong he will punch on top of the opponent bokken on his blunt kisaki and instructor will hear that sound.

[This is example of parrying, 1. and 2. kumitachi kanren, my two deshis (2 kyu at that time).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50r6jaSvzus&ab_channel=AikidoRijeka)

Comment: @Sardathrion please see the edit